# Render a React Component Using Multiple Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently having an issue rendering a component using multiple ternary operators.

Here is my code:

```
{data.shippingData ? (
   <CheckoutPayment data={data} setData={setData} />
  ) : data && data.agree === true ? (
                console.log("Hello World")
              ) : (
                    <CheckoutShipping setData={setData} />
                  )}
```

The `<CheckoutPayment />` and `<CheckoutShipping />` components successfully rendered without issues, the issue lies in having to render another component using this condition `data && data.agree === true`. In the above code, I tried using `console.log` to log "Hello World" but to no avail.

Here is how the data model is structured in the `<CheckoutPayment />`:

`{shippingData: {firstName, lastName, streetAddress, state, city, phoneNumber }, agree: true}`

I took the data from the `<CheckoutPayment />` component into the global state where I have to pass the data to another component.

The data is available in the state. In fact, I `console.log` the data to confirm if it was there in which it was.

What I have in mind to achieve is:

1. If there is `shippingData` in data object I want to render `<CheckoutPayment />` else if
2. There is `shippingData and agree` in the data object I want to `console.log("Hello World")` else
3. Render `<CheckoutShipping />`

My question is, is there a way I might have misused the ternary operator or I am not getting something right.

Answer (score 5):

Why not put this in a function, and call that function from render()?

```
getComponentToRender() {
   if(shippingData) {
     return <CheckoutPayment data={data} setData={setData} />;
   } else if(!(data || data.agree)) {
      return <CheckoutShipping />;
   } else {
     console.log("Hello World");
   }
   return null;
}
```

Inside your render you can do the following:

```
render() {
  return(
   <>{this.getComponentToRender()}</>
 );
}
```

Comment: bro, you forgot the `return` keyword on the second `if`

Comment: Thanks @nouvist. updated the same.

Comment: Yea the key here is to console log before returning null or whatever placeholder is actually supposed to render

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using a functional component. Well, I have done this before using a functional component but still didn't work. I think the problem should be how I am getting the data. The structure of the data is in this format `{shippingData: {…}, agree: true}`

Comment: @OgeObubu I think if you can share the data object, or its model, it may help

Comment: @Kanishk Anand updated

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with the ternary, just that console.log() returns undefined and won't render anything. I think child.render() is what ultimately runs, the child instance is normally an object not a function

You're trying to render the result of `console.log()`'s return (`undefined`) as a sibling node (which would both need to be wrapped in a parent or a fragment like `<></>`

You should remove the console.log from the render return, and just

1. console.log before returning anything
2. render null or whatever placeholder error should exist there, maybe just a text node `Hello World`

Comment: Probably I am not being clear enough. I replaced the component that ought to be there with `console.log`. The component doesn't even render despite having the data. I am writing a React Multiple Form Function

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys for the contributions. I do not take it likely. I have been able to figure the code out.

I changed the movement of the code. I had to `return console.log` to the top of the code and it worked out fine.